# Tensorflow model training constant loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've been trying to train a model for image classification for vehicles, but i keep getting loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000 on every training epoch.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import pathlib

data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cars_photos', origin="C:\\Users\\User\\.keras\\datasets\\cars_photos")
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

num_classes = 1

model = Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs=10
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)
```

I downloaded image myself using image of size 180x180 as minimun and 1920 x 1024 as max. Also the images have JPEG and a few PNG format.

i followed [image classification tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) and tried searching for a solution yet none found.

Comment: Are you sure you have one class? Because the minimum number of classes is two.

Comment: Yeah, right, I was wondering that too. what is the output of `print(class_names)` this line, @SaltyCode

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
layers.Dense(num_classes, activation = 'sigmoid')
```

and this:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Now the results on each training epoch is loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: (changes) - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: (changes)

Comment: There's some improvement i believe, now only the loss and val_loss remains the same with 0.0000e+00 values, while accuracy and val_accuracy changed to 0.605 and 0.0526 constantly

Comment: What are you classifying? How many classes do you have?

Comment: Im classifying vehicles types and so far only one class for initial testing.

After changing the compile method it seems to be working but after the 2nd epoch the outputs are loss: 6.7703e-18 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 2.6361e-25 - val_accuracy: 1.0000. Really low numbers for loss and val_loss variables and constant acc and val_accuracy.

Also when trying to predict i get 100% predictions for one image that is true to the vehicle type and another one which is not.

Comment: @SaltyCode You need two classes minimum, one class makes no sense.